# Java ESAPI IMPLEMENTATION

Tags: filter, xss, owasp, esapi

I've a question regarding owasp ESAPI interface for xss protection.To keep it simple short and straight I'm doing a source code review using fortify.
The application implement ESAPI and make call to ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(user input) and does not do any further validation and prints the output. Is this still vulnerable to xss
PS: The reflection point is inside a html element. 
I've gone through all the posts regarding ESAPI interface in stack overflow, but couldn't quite get it
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Let me know if any further information is required on this.
Sorry if my way of presenting the question is odd.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me know if any further information is required on this.
Sorry if my way of presenting the question is odd.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canonicalize` alone doesn't prevent xss at all. It decodes data, but you want the opposite, to encode the data.

Not only does it allow content like `<script>alert(1)</script>` straight-through, but it also decodes `&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;` from a non-executable script to a executable one.

The method you want instead is `encodeForHTML`. This will encode the data so it can be inserted safely into an HTML context, so `<` will become `&lt;` and so on.

Also, check if you're already doing HTML encoding by checking whether these characters are accepted. Some templating languages and tags do encoding automatically.

Comment: Have a small doubt here.here we are also calling the encoder aswell by using ESAPI.encodr(). canonicalize(). So doesn't the encoder encode the decoded output from canonicalize method

Comment: @itzkmv The encoder will only do encoding if you call one of the encoding methods on it. A few of the methods do decoding instead.

Comment: Have a doubt, doesn't the encodevmethod  in ESAPI.encoder(). canonicalize () encode the decoded output by the canonicalize method

Comment: Thanks for concise yet precise answer

Comment: No, `ESAPI.encoder` method retrieves the encoder object. It doesn't do anything with the strings until you call the specific methods on it.

Comment: This answer should be a wiki

Comment: @fgb with the same input filter i
in place what will< and > be decoded to

Comment: @itzkmv < and > can't be decoded to anything. They would not change.